# Binding search results to data grid

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

I want to add search functionality to my program.  There's a class which has this function:

```
public DataTable Search()
        {
            string SQL = "Select * from Customer where " + mField + " like '%" + mValue + "%'";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = dm.GetData(SQL);
            return (dt);

        }
```

There are setter and getter properties for `mField` and `mValue`.  `DM` is the object of  class `DataManagement`, which has a method `GetData`:

```
public DataTable GetData(string SQL)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();

        command.Connection = clsConnection.GetConnection();
        command.CommandText = SQL;
        dbAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        dbAdapter.Fill(DataTable);
        return (DataTable);
    }
```

The search functionality is currently implemented like this:

```
private void btnfind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //cust is the object of class customer//
        if (tbCustName.Text != "")
        {
            cust.Field="CustName";
            cust.Value = tbCustName.Text;
        }
        else if (tbAddress.Text != "")
        {
            cust.Value = tbAddress.Text;
            cust.Field="Address";
        }
        else if (tbEmail.Text != "")
        {
            cust.Value = tbEmail.Text;
            cust.Field="Email";
        }
        else if (tbCell.Text != "")
        {
            cust.Value = tbCell.Text;
            cust.Field = "Cell";
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = cust.Search();
        dgCustomer.DataSource = dt;
        RefreshGrid();
    }

    private void RefreshGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = cust.GetCustomers();
        dgCustomer.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

This is not working. I don't know why. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `DataBind()` statement in your `RefreshGrid()` method to have your new results actually shown on the Grid.

```
private void RefreshGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = cust.GetCustomers();
    dgCustomer.DataSource = dt;
    dgCustomer.DataBind();
}
```

---

Consider modifying your other method as well:

1. **Your ad-hoc SQL has a SQL injection vulnerability**. Stop everything until you fix that!
2. `btnfind_Click` doesn't need to end up calling `cust.Search()` twice.

   ```
   private void btnfind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //<snip>
       // no need to do all this twice.
       //  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       // dt = cust.Search();
       // dgCustomer.DataSource = dt;
       RefreshGrid();

   }
   ```

Comment: i mean do i edit the previous refereshGrid function or do i make a new function?

Answer (score 0):

Your `RefreshGrid` method is overwriting the `DataSource` you set in `btnfind_Click`... don't call it, just call `DataBind`

```
private void btnfind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...

    DataTable dt = cust.Search();
    dgCustomer.DataSource = dt;
    dgCustomer.DataBind();

}
```

By the way, you don't need to assign a new `DataTable` to dt if you're immediately setting it to the result of `cust.Search`... you're just creating an instance for nothing (I fixed it in the code above)